# Implementing secure pages and $rootScope is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Inside my angularjs app. I have userService which has method for determination if user is loggedIn or not. `userService.user.loggedIn()`

now I want to use that service in order to implement secure pages, where I will redirect user upon this `userService.user.loggedIn()` statement.

my app.js looks like this

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module("myApp",
        ["common.services",
            "$rootScope",
            "ui.router",
            "ui.mask",
            "userService",          
            "ui.bootstrap"]);        

    app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider",
            function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $rootScope) {
                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

                $stateProvider
                    .state("index", {
                        url: "/",
                        templateUrl: "app/index.html",
                    })
                    // Home page /* SECURED */
                    .state("home", {
                        url: "/home",
                        templateUrl: "app/home/home.html",
                        controller: "HomeController as vm",
                        data: {
                            requiresLogin: true
                        }
                    })
                     // Login
                    .state("login", {
                        url: "/login",
                        templateUrl: "app/login/login.html",
                        controller: "LoginController as vm"
                    })

            }]
    );
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (e, to, userService) {
          if (to.data && to.data.requiresLogin) {
            if (!userService.user.loggedIn()) {
              //token not found/not valid
              e.preventDefault();
              $location.path('/login');
            }
          }
        });
}());
```

Inside console I'm getting

> ReferenceError: $rootScope is not defined
>
> $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (e, to, appUserService,
>   $rootScope)...

Answer (score 0):

It's not in the array of injectable:

Try this:

```
app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$rootScope",
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $rootScope) {
```

Comment: nope, I injected into the app.config. same error remains.

Answer (score 0):

You can only place providers in config. So place your $rootScope.$on function in app controller.